# Symbol access to a class inside module in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, routes, symbols

I have two class `Company::Users` and `Users`. I am trying to `Devise` for these two models. While for `Users`, I can directly do:

```
devise_for :users
```

I am not sure how to point `Devise` to `Company::Users` in routes. The line below throws a `uninitialized constant CompanyUsers` error

```
devise_for :company_users
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `devise_for :users, :path => "company"` try this

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

`:"company/users"` is the right way to access a class inside a module.